# Update com CRUD genérico

Tags: php, crud

Estou usando um CRUD genérico desenvolvido pelo William F. Leite e me atende muito bem, mas estou com uma dificuldade para fazer uma alteração, já tentei algumas possibilidades mas sem sucesso, o que tenho é isso:

```
// INSTANCIO A TABELA
$crud = Crud::getInstance($pdo, 'ubsSeq');

// BUSCO A ÚLTIMA SEQUÊNCIA DA TABELA
$sqlSeq = "SELECT max(valor) AS Sequencia FROM ubsSeq WHERE nome = 'seq_laudo'";
$arrayParamSeq = array();
$ResSeq = $crud->getSQLGeneric($sqlSeq, $arrayParamSeq, TRUE);

foreach ($ResSeq as $Seq) { 

    // ATRIBUO + 1 A SEQUÊNCIA RESGATADA
    $Seq = $Seq->Sequencia + 1;         

    // AQUI ALTERO O VALOR DA SEQUÊNCIA
    $arrayUp = array('Valor' => $Seq);  
    $arrayCond = array('Nome=' => 'seq_laudo');  
    $resposta = $crud->update($arrayUp, $arrayCond);    

}
```

A variável `$Seq = $Seq->Sequencia + 1;` está com o valor correto, mas não consigo fazer o `update`, a tentativa que fiz foi colocar aspas na variável `$seq` pois a mesma será armazenada em um campo `varchar`, mas também não deu certo.

Comment: Já tentou fazer o cast para string? Ex.: `$arrayUp = array('Valor' => (string)$Seq);`

Comment: Olá @Thomas, essa tentativa eu ainda não tinha testado, acabei de fazer e ainda não consegui, valeu pela dica.

Comment: Uma coisa que acabo de perceber é na `$arrayCond` que deve ser a condição do WHERE: o nome do campo é mesmo `Nome=`? Acho que você pôs um `=` depois do nome do campo

Comment: Tambem acho que o constragimento seja  $arrayCond = array('Nome=' => 'seq_laudo');  deveria ser $arrayCond = array('Nome' => 'seq_laudo'); Acho que tambem não é aconselhavel alterar o valor da variavel do foreach $Seq na minha opinião deveria usar outra variavel para manipular o valor Sequencia

Comment: Olá @TiagoGomes, segundo a documentação do autor a sintaxe é essa mesma, inclusive tenha uma outra rotina de alteração que funciona normalmente, mas nesse caso não, obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: @adventistapr Qual o resultado que você esperava e qual você está tendo? Qual o valor do `Valor` no banco depois que o foreach executa?

Comment: No select você usa `nome` e no update está usando `Nome`, já verificou se é o nome da coluna poderia ser case-sensitive?

Comment: Olá pessoa, a linha $resposta = $crud->update($arrayUp, $arrayCond); está me dando como resultado 'false' e conseguente mente o campo Valor não está sendo atualizado.